# JQuery Ajax - Post - Value corrupted

Tags: jquery, ajax, delphi, type-conversion, rad-studio

First time I've ever encountered this strange situation. I've already worked with Ajax and parameters of different types. I tried it to solve with `contentType`, but it didn't seem to work.

I tried to play with formats like **UTF-8** of the document, and `contentType` as mentioned above.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Test",
    type: "POST",
    data: 
    {
        'ID':$(this).attr("ID"),
        'Date':$(this).attr("Date")
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false
})
```

> ID=12345&Date=01.01.2018+00%3A00%3A00 // Is
>
> ID=12345&Date=01.01.2018 00:00:00 // Should be

Because of this I cannot convert it to a `double` type in Delphi (Rad Studio):

> *Variant of Type (UnicodeString) could not be converted into Double*

Comment: I don't see the connection with Delphi. Please elaborate, how is this related to Delphi?

Comment: The Problem itself is not related to Delphi, i just thought it may help unterstanding the Situation better. Also maybe someone had the same Problem in the same Situation and can recognize it easier. I can remove it, if it should not be mentioned.

Comment: Your data has been html encoded. You can html decode it if need be.

Comment: Missinterpreted the failure, it comes from my delphi application, but still thanks for all comments it may be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your string has been html encoded.  Html Decode it on your server side before converting it to a Date (or double in your case?).

[Most ajax libraries will do this automatically.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18382054/3183491)  That is probably what yours is doing, hence the html encoding in your date strings. It is strange you've never noticed it before, as it's rather normal behavior on a post.

To fix in Delphi, look at the `HTTPApp` unit. `HTTPDecode` and `HTMLDecode` (as well as the Encode functions). You should find this in your *Source/Win32/Internet* folder.

[See this SO question as the above paragraph answer came from there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657105/delphi-html-decode)